# apt-get not found after running some purge commands

Tags: command-line, 18.04, apt, purge

I am very new to ubuntu, my OS is ubuntu 18.04 LTS
during installation of some applications,

I ran following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

mkdir ppa-purge && cd ppa-purge && wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/ppa-purge/ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr56_all.deb && wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/a/aptitude/aptitude_0.6.6-1ubuntu1_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i ./*.deb
```

after a certain stage, i discover my terminal firing error of apt

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

I am not getting how to figure out the issue. Can any expert help me fix the issue?

Comment: How could you loose apt?  Is dpkg on your system? `dpkg -l | grep dpkg`

Comment: dpkg is available but how can i get the apt-get

Comment: Were `ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr56_all.deb` and `aptitude_0.6.6-1ubuntu1_i386.deb` the only deb files in the directory, or were there others present when you ran the `dpkg -i ./*.deb` command? What is your actual system architecture (`uname -m`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, make a backup first from your important data.

I hope wget is also present on your system.

```
mkdir $HOME/apt-download && cd $HOME/apt-download
```

Next we draw the required packages.

For **64-bit** system.

```
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.6ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
```

Next is

```
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg5.0_1.6.6ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
```

Install both

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Next we test apt

```
sudo apt -f install
```

For **32-bit**

```
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.6ubuntu0.1_i386.deb
```

and

```
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg5.0_1.6.6ubuntu0.1_i386.deb
```

The steps for installing is the same as for the 64-bit packages.

Comment: I would be hesitant to use `*.deb`. since the OP may have other uninstalled packages, and since misusing wildcards is a possible cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much nobody. It helped. My apt is  back. I  tried so many ways to get it back but failed. Now that you provided me a solution it worked. Thanks a lot man.